# How do I pull data from database into Visual Studio to produce a "weekly scheduling" system?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i need some help with my codes to allow me to create a simple weekly scheduling system. But i keep having errors saying that i am missing an operator, but i am unable to solve the problem.

Here are the codes from my vs project:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public String databaseFile = "C:\\Temp\\database.mdb";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
    public DataTable BindGridviewData()
    {
        DataTable dt;
        OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + databaseFile + ";");
        using (Conn)
        {
            Conn.Open();


            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Satellite ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;",  Conn);
            using (OleDbDataAdapter oDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    oDA.Fill(dt); 
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when i run these codes, it keeps giving me this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in         System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'RANDOM() LIMIT 1'.
```

I would like to know how to solve this problem as i can't seem to find any solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking to use `RAND()`.

```
//...
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Satellite ORDER BY RAND();",  Conn);
//...
```

There's also a chance you may not need the `ORDER BY` clause at all. If the order doesn't matter, why order anything?